# Fourier Transform - convolution theorem

Tags: fourier, convolution

I have been studying the Fourier Transform and the convolution theorem is not clear to me.

Sometimes, I see this:

[image]

But other times I see this:

[image]

Which one is correct? Where is this constant factor from?

Comment: These two different definitions. You should make sure which one you are working with.

Comment: And how do I know which one I am working with? I mean, what is the source of the difference between these two?

Comment: You know there are different ways to define the F.T., right? They are different because of a factor of \$1/2\pi\$ in either the forward or inverse FT, or possibly a factor of \$1/\sqrt{2\pi}\$ included in each. You need to know which definition of the F.T. and I.F.T. your source is using.

Comment: It's about the convention. The definitions are usually communicated before the usage. Take a look https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-the-1-sqrt-2-pi-in-the-definition-of-the-fourier-transform.487312/

Comment: I didn't know about the other definition, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ThePhoton and @EugeneSh., it turns out there are different definitions of Fourier Transforms.

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-the-1-sqrt-2-pi-in-the-definition-of-the-fourier-transform.487312/